# SetOnclickListener brain lock on how to do

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a button that cause an image to display the image full screen (no/title or notify Bar).
I throw up a toast that say you can tap the screen to restore to normal size with selection buttons up top of the screen.  I'm having a brain lock on how to register the SetOnClickListener for the image screen.  I have as code.

```
 public void getFull(View v)
      {
       OnScreen=1;   
       if(ScreenNoBars==0)ScreenNoBars=1;
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);  //gets rid of title bar   
       ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
       img.setImageDrawable(getMyImage(0));
       setContentView(img);
       img.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) v);   //<<< problem here
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tap Image to restore buttons or Rotate
       device.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can handle ImageView click directly by doing this

```
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Image Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //do operation
  }
});
```

Comment: wow. I'm new to Java and mostly a beginner at Android... but 35 years as a C programmer. I get blown away sometimes at some of the elegance that can be had in Android with the right mind behind it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you set the image and clickable.  ie `ImageView blah; blah.setClickable(true);`